# Why touch - doesn't return any error and yet is not creating the file -?

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils

I wanted to create a file called "-" through the command touch.

```
touch -
```

I expected an error or the creation of the file, however no error and no file creation.

Also, how can I create the file called "-". Is it even possible?

Comment: You can also do `> -` to create the file without using touch.

Answer (score 3):

As documented in `man touch`:

> A  FILE  argument string of - is handled specially and causes touch to change the times of the file associated with standard output.

To create a file of that name, use a longer path, e.g.:

```
touch ./-
```

To see the difference, try

```
( echo a ; sleep 2; ) > file ; date ; stat file
```

versus

```
( echo a ; sleep 2; touch - ) > file ; date ; stat file
```

In the first case, the modification time will be 2 seconds before the actual time. In the second case, it will be almost identical to it.

Comment: Interesting, I learned something new today. What's a common use case for this?

Comment: However it's kind of misleading the fact that doesn't exit with error state